# Fastest way to migrate Gitlab branches to another project

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

We are having a project with around 1000 Gitlab branches.

We would like to move around 300 existing branches to another existing ( completely unrelated ) project.

What is the fastest and efficient way to do it ?

Comment: "Another project", meaning an completely unrelated project or a fork of the other project? Do you mean to move commits or just create branches with the same names? You shouls elaborate on what exactly you want to do to make your question easier to answer.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks for input.

Comment: You could `fork` it and then `manually delete` the branches you don't need. (could also write a script to do it.). You have to `fork` because that's the only way to clone the repo into someone else's ownership. And you need the `git` histor, so..